# Using DATE as part of a composite foreign key in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, date, mariadb, foreign-keys

I have a table that, minimally, has

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T (
    A int(11) NOT NULL,
    B date NOT NULL
);
```

`A` and `B` themselves happen to have FK constraints later on, but since this isn't part of the MWE I don't include them.

I then have another table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS U (
    C int(11) NOT NULL,
    D date NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (C) REFERENCES T(A),
    FOREIGN KEY (D) REFERENCES T(B)
);
```

But I get

```
#1005 - Can't create table `DBName`.`u` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

I realised that the problem is actually with the `date` constraint. I read that this cannot be done because `T(B)` is not either unique or primary. However, this shouldn't be a big issue because I also have another foreign key `T(A)` that should be unique.

However, I also read that this is only an issue in MySQL, and that InnoDB has an extension that supports it if, for any reason, you need it. I tried adding `ENGINE=InnoDB` at the end, but this did not change anything.

Can this be done, and if not, what's the best practice to have a foreign key of `(int(11), date)`?

Further details:

- Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
- Server type: MariaDB
- Server version: 10.4.27-MariaDB
- Protocol version: 10
- Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
- Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.2.0

Running through XAMPP with Apache/2.4.64 (Win64).

This is being run in the PHPMyAdmin SQL console, at the database level.

Comment: @mandy8055 so if I understand right, `A` and `B` are not unique themselves, but the combination `(A, B)` is. It also does work, yes, so thank you for that. If you want to make an answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're encountering the issue due to the fact that in MySQL, you can only reference columns that have either a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE constraint. One way to fix this, is you can create a **composite UNIQUE constraint** on columns A and B in table T.

```sql
ALTER TABLE T
ADD UNIQUE (A, B);
```

This should create the table U without any errors, and the foreign keys will reference the composite key (A, B) in table T.

***[DBFIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iHj3WobUMubwH6ELfGxwYu/0)***